# How to suppress the Adobe Acrobat PDF popup in Chrome's toolbar?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, adobe-acrobat

Whenever I open a PDF, this popup opens, and it's driving me nuts as its checkbox doesn't work:

[image: Screenshot]

How do I prevent it from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Extensions tab (`chrome://extensions`), check the Developer Mode box, click the "Background page" link in front of the "Inspect views" label, click the "Console" tab, and paste this line:

```
utilities.setCookie("always-show-pdf-menu", "false", 365 * 20)
```